# How to fix retrofit errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have parse the data from this link

https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

But I am getting error as

E/on Failure :: retrofit errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Below is the code which I done.

```
class RetrofitService {
    val liveUserResponse:MutableLiveData<List<ContactBase>> = MutableLiveData()

    companion object Factory {
        var gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
        fun create(): ApiInterface {
            Log.e("retrofit","create")

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl("https://api.androidhive.info/")
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
    fun loadContactsData(): MutableLiveData<List<ContactBase>>? {

        Log.e("loadAndroidData","yes")

        val retrofitCall  = create().getContacts()

        retrofitCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ContactBase>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ContactBase>>, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.e("on Failure :", "retrofit error"+t)
                Log.e("on Failure :", "retrofit error"+call)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ContactBase>>, response: retrofit2.Response<List<ContactBase>>) {
                val list  = response.body()
                for (i in list.orEmpty()){
                    Log.e("on response 1:", ""+i)
                }
                liveUserResponse.value = list
                Log.e("hasActiveObservers 1", liveUserResponse.hasActiveObservers().toString()+" check")
                Log.e("on response 2 :", liveUserResponse.toString()+" check")

            }

        })

        return liveUserResponse
    }
}
```

But it's always going to Failure state.

```
data class ContactBase (val contacts : List<Contacts>)

data class Contacts (

    val id : String,
    val name : String,
    val email : String,
    val address : String,
    val gender : String,
    val phone : Phone
)

 data class Phone (

    val mobile : String,
    val home : String,
    val office : String
)

 interface ApiInterface{
    @GET("contacts/")
    fun getContacts(): Call<List<ContactBase>>
}



class AndroidViewModel:ViewModel(){
    private val retrofitService = RetrofitService()

    fun getContactsData(): MutableLiveData<List<ContactBase>>?{
        return  retrofitService.loadContactsData()
    }
}
```

I cross verified the url too and pojo class. But it always go to failure case in retrofit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the incomming JSON starts with a `{` and not with a `[` which means it's an object and not an array of objects.

So you should be having a class that has an array of `Contact` in order to make that call successful.

A small heads up: Since you are using GSON, your model classes would need the implementation of `@SerializedName(string)` annotation above the variables.

Comment: @Starvo Xhardha Thanks. i made as serializedName for all pojo classes . But I already having the pojo class  of Contact but how to implement in successful call?   val retrofitCall  = create().getContacts() //here it wraps only the contactbase but how to get the list contacts?

Comment: create a cdata lass which you may call `ContactsResponse` and inside it add a variable val contacts : List<Contacts> with the serialized name of you contacts key. And in the retrofit method return `Call<ContactsResponse>`